# Phonegap app not showing in android simulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-activity, android-emulator, hybrid-mobile-app

I am new to phonegap framework. I did couple of things to get my first phonegap app up and running. Somehow the app isnt showing up in the simulator eventhough its showing the message "Completed cordova run android". What am i missing here ?

I did these things:
1.)Installed phonegap 4.2.0-0.24.0
2.)In my .profile file, I have added these lines:

export ANDROID_HOME="/home/kpk/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/home/kpk/android/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"

3.) Executed command "android" in the terminal and updated few things
4.) Created a AVD by clicking manage AVD
5.) Started the avd
6.) Executed phonegap create my-app
7.) cd my-app
8.) phonegap local run my-app

Its giving me success message. But I am not able to find the app in the simulator